# Can triggers call PHP Scripts?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a trigger, but mysql doesn't like it:

Code :

```
create trigger triggers_on_comand_line AFTER UPDATE on test1 
for each row 
begin 
IF total_volume >= used_volume
THEN
\! echo "php -f /home/test.php" 
END;
```

I got this error :

** MySQL said: Documentation 1064 - 064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '! echo "php -f /home/test.php" at line 6  **

Thanks

Comment: I don't like it too. :) And I don't like your question, because you provide little information. :) What do you mean by "doesn't like"? Do not run? Throw an exception? Just silently do nothing?

Comment: As far as I know... No, you can't.

Comment: i Provided the Error message i executedmy trigger in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Hm, wait. Per UDF maybe.. take a look at [Invoking a PHP script from a mysql trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1467369/693207)

Comment: Please make your question more informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call php scripts if you install [mysql_udf_sys](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are writing in MYSQL language, and execute in query language, but the line "system php -f /home/test.php" is written in PHP language.

Comment: I want to execute php script inside my trigger any solution plz

Answer (score 0):

Tx to this post [1](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,170973,257815#msg-257815), use :

```
\! echo "php -f /home/test.php"
```