# Execute batch file on remote server when database get updated by application

Tags: database, triggers

I need to execute a batch file on remote server when database get updated by application

running in web browser/client side.For example if user click on Submit button of form

and data get entered in database , a batch file should get executed on server which will

perform certain tasks.can DB trigger perform such tasks.. ( i doubt)...? I wish to use windows 2008 server and MYSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Invoking a PHP script from a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger)

Comment: is there any other ways by which this can be achieved? i wish to use JAVA as platform.

Comment: Obviously I was wrong. I have edited my answer, you might find a solution at the link provided.