# How can I alert my program if a specific database table has been added/updated/deleted a record on it?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a server application and client application that the database is shared within a network, What I want to happen is that when the client application inserted/updated/deleted data from a specific table I want the server to be alerted and run some code on it.

How can I possibly achieve this? Any ideas will be a big help! thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use a trigger for push notifications, or keep lastModified information to check for pull notification.
You probably want the former,

*edit* You can use sys_exec('program') from https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys to call an external program from a trigger. Just use that to call whatever server code you have.
Examples and setup instructions can be found via google. e.g.  http://bernardodamele.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/command-execution-with-mysql-udf.html

Comment: So, how can I catch that trigger thing on my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger has some answers on how to call a different program from a trigger. You can use sys_exec to call an external program, which then runs whatever code you wanted.

Comment: @cheol.lui Updated answer with some more information on how to use sys_exec, and where to get it from.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what type of database you were using.  If you were using MS SQL Server, I'd suggest having a look at their [StreamInsight](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/streaming-data.aspx) which lets you write "adapters" that deal with data in real-time as it is saved.

I don't know if you'll be able to access/incorporate that in your existing server application though.  But depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might not have to.

Comment: I'm using MYSQL DB sir, i have tagged it on the question :)