# What security risks are there in using MySQL triggers to execute PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, security, triggers

I've searched around and [found a way to do exactly this](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html). But I'm hesitant because I occasionally read that its a ["security risk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger). Unfortunately, nobody ever elaborates on why. I, personally, can't think of any security risk that wouldn't involve an attacker already having permissions they shouldn't. The MySQL/PHP servers are running on the same machine. so there's no public requests between the MySQL and PHP.

The PHP script triggered, will make an API call to a web service on a third-party CRM/ESP that keeps a simplified version of certain tables on a their server. Our marketing team could then log into the CRM's GUI and send emails, gather information, and plan marketing campaigns without the need to bother the dev team.

The tables on this server do not mirror ours, they contain only information they would need. The reason I want to use triggers is to keep their information as up-to-date as possible and have that logic in one place, instead of scattered throughout the project.

**UPDATE:**
I always sanitize/validate any Forms that touch MySQL. I never store PHP in my tables. I never use FTP (SFTP using a .pem instead of a password).
The  script that will be executing will be a single file I created that won't change which is going through the same framework I'm using (zend). The only variables passed to the script will be the row's id (which will be validated as an INT).
I'm thinking of not doing this because of performance. And making PHP execute Asynchronously is possible, but difficult and not worth my time to implement. But I'm still curious, Other than the performance penalty, how would the security concerns be any different than say a web service? I mean you definitely have to sanitize/validate just like you would a web service, so given that, what concerns would there be?

Comment: It's a security risk because it can execute arbitrary code.  That code can do anything, up to and including DROP TABLE STUDENTS.  Architecting an application by sending code across the wire sounds like a really bad idea, and you don't need it for what you want to do anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways your app can be compromised, such as SQL injection, a sniffed FTP password, or a vulnerability in the code itself.  It is generally a good idea to keep these things as localized as possible to prevent a breach in one area from cascading.

For example, say that you are storing sensitive data in your database.  Typically, you would encrypt this data somehow, using a salt and key that is not stored in the database itself.  Then, if your database is compromised by SQL injection, the attackers may cause damage, but they will not be able to steal the sensitive information.  However, if you are executing PHP stored as text in your database, the attacker will certainly realize this and update it to execute his code, from whence he can figure out how you are encrypting the sensitive data and unencrypt it.

In short, SQL injection is very common (even if you are following best practices, nobody says the intern who walks in next year will) and it is therefore not safe to execute code stored in a database.

**EDIT**: after reading your link more closely, I need to restate some things.  I don't see a particular security risk in this, but this seems to really contravene the separation of data and logic.  Further, mysql is not async and there is no way that this can possibly scale under load...

Comment: I don't know how to chooses this, but this answered my question.