# MySQL trigger to RabbitMQ

Tags: python, mysql, triggers, rabbitmq

I looking for a way to transfer a SQL record to RabbitMQ.

What I need is whenever a new record is insert to the table I want to transfer this record (as JSON or any other format) to the RabbitMQ.

I read about executing an external script with sys_exec() (like Python or Java) but I would like to know how it should be done and if this is the best way.

Comment: Can you just do it on application level?

Comment: Hi, its application that I do not want to change, cant it be done from the SQL?

Comment: Yes, it can. See this question for details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

[ssimicro/lib_mysqludf_amqp: Publish messages via AMQP directly from MySQL](https://github.com/ssimicro/lib_mysqludf_amqp) seems to fit the bill.

Then you'd be able to do this (cut'n'paste from the README):

```
SET @AMQP_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672';
SET @AMQP_EXCHANGE = 'udf';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Accounts';

DELIMITER ;;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_insert_on_accounts`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `after_insert_on_accounts` AFTER INSERT ON `accounts` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @message_id = (SELECT lib_mysqludf_amqp_sendjson(@AMQP_URL, @AMQP_EXCHANGE, 'accounts.insert', json_object('id', NEW.id, 'username', NEW.username)));
END ;;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_update_on_accounts`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `after_update_on_accounts` AFTER UPDATE ON `accounts` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @message_id = (SELECT lib_mysqludf_amqp_sendjson(@AMQP_URL, @AMQP_EXCHANGE, 'accounts.update', json_object('id', NEW.id, 'username', NEW.username)));
END ;;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_delete_on_accounts`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `after_delete_on_accounts` AFTER DELETE ON `accounts` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @message_id = (SELECT lib_mysqludf_amqp_sendjson(@AMQP_URL, @AMQP_EXCHANGE, 'accounts.delete', json_object('id', OLD.id, 'username', OLD.username)));
END ;;

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO accounts (username) values ('jdoe');
UPDATE accounts SET username = 'jsmith';
DELETE FROM accounts WHERE id = last_insert_id();
```

I suspect though, that it opens a new connection to RabbitMQ and logs in for every message, which is likely going to yield bad performance. But I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking into doing something similar, it seems MySQL triggers may be the key:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html

and using those to execute something which posts to RabbitMQ

Comment: Can you share with me how you are posting on RabbitMQ from the trigger?

Comment: using the sys_exec() udf plugin in MySQL you can execute arbitrary code, so my plan is to hook up a python script (or something similar) which just sends along the event to RabbitMQ using their python API. I haven't had a chance to implement it yet but that's the plan anyway!

Comment: If python needs to be started up for every execution of the trigger, performance is going to be horrible.