# Can we send SNMP traps from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a systemEvents table.

Trigger will be running, so whenever a new row is added, it should fetch the details from the systemEvents table and send a details to the SNMP manager as a SNMP trap/inform.

Comment: Maybe a workqueue might help which can be invoked through a trigger

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258126/send-mysql-alerts-by-snmp-traps

Comment: 2. http://www.masterzen.fr/software-contributions/mysql-snmp-monitor-mysql-with-snmp/

Answer (score 0):

For **one of your own tables**, you can add functions to MySQL through its [user-defined function (UDF)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) interface.   This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger?lq=1) shows how to invoke PHP scripts through MySQL triggers (though similar should be ok for any scripts eg net-snmp ones to send traps).

EDIT: However after seeing comments from @Joddy, I realise now that it is probably the built in systemEvents table you want, i.e. it is state of whole MySQL you want, so one of tools he mentions may be simpler than UDF approach.