# Pusher: Trigger pusher when mysql data change

Tags: push-notification, pusher

I'm trying to use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) for making a real time push notification. I want to trigger the pusher when mysql data is change. Can someone help me with it? I'm new on this pusher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to to do this is to trigger an event via Pusher after you have performed the database interaction.

e.g.

```
// Connect and interact with database
$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "database_name");

$value = $_POST["activity-name"];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO activities (column) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
$stmt->execute();

// TODO: check the INSERT was successful.

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

// TODO: Only trigger if the DB interaction was successful

// Create Pusher instance (assuming the Pusher library has been required)
$pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, APP_ID);

// Trigger the event representing the new data that's been inserted
$pusher->trigger('activities', 'activity-created' ['name' => $value]);
```

If the database interact were for an `UPDATE` then you can use a different event name.

```
$pusher->trigger('activities', 'activity-updated' ['name' => $value]);
```

Alternatively you could set up a database trigger and have another script execute and interact with Pusher when a change takes place. See [Invoking a PHP script from a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger)

Comment: $stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

// If your application crashes right here; event is never sent -> bad practice

// Create Pusher instance (assuming the Pusher library has been required)
$pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, APP_ID);