# Execute Java upon change in a mysql database

Tags: java

I wonder how to trigger the execution of java code upon a change in a federated table. I have researched this topic but only leads me to more confussion. I am new to databaes. Thank you

Comment: On an Arduino? Surely not..?

Comment: This question leads me to confusion

Comment: See this question about executing a PHP script via trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1467369/1247781

Comment: The issue is how to do it on a FEDERATED table. Triggers are not realiable on this type of databases. Is there any other way to do it without ussing triggers?