# Listeners in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Is there anyway to make a listener for any update happens in database (mysql) using php?
for example. 
if you make any update in database (change an entry or element) it will notify you or make a specific function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use [SQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) directly. Beside that PHP got it 's own [classes in the SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php) for event driven functionality.

**Trigger example with SQL (taken from the examples from the link above)**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE account (acct_num INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2));
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;

mysql> SET @sum = 0;
mysql> INSERT INTO account VALUES(137,14.98),(141,1937.50),(97,-100.00);
mysql> SELECT @sum AS 'Total amount inserted';
```

This example creates a trigger called ins_sum which calculates the sum of the inserted values after an insert statement is executed. After an insert statement you can select the @sum variable by a simple select statement.