# Call PHP from trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, xmlhttprequest, phpmailer

I'm using XAMPP, I have a mysql database and I need to send a mail for every INSERT on the table. I configured PHPMailer and I need to make an http request to the script from an after insert trigger on the table. PHPMailer is working well but I don't have any idea about the http request.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far, it makes it easier to get things working if possible.

Comment: I donwloaded the example code to send an email from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and it's working when I call it in the browser. I need to call this script from a trigger in mysql, I don't have the trigger because this is what I need.

Comment: Have you read [Invoking a PHP script from a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger) yet? (Please also read the parts that explain why it is not such a good idea to do that).