# mysql trigger fire in phpmyadmin but doesn't fire in php code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers

I have a website built with codeigniter
In phpmyadmin i have created this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `After_Add_Order` AFTER INSERT ON `order`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.points IS NOT NULL) THEN
update users set users.points = users.points + new.points where users.user_id = new.owner_id;
END IF;
END
```

when i insert data in phpmyadmin the trigger get fired but when i insert data within php the trigger doesn't fire even though the points within inserted order has value.
and this is my php code

```
if ($this->db->insert('order', $data)) {
   $id = $this->db->insert_id();
   return $id;
}
```

Any help

Comment: Please don't try execute trigger on php . its bad practice [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger)

Comment: the trigger in phpmyadmin not in php

Comment: In `$data`, can you confirm that `points` is not null?

Comment: yes it's inserted in the database with the right value

Comment: Double-check that your app is connecting to the same MySQL instance that phpMyAdmin is connecting to. You may have created the trigger in one MySQL instance, but not the one your app is using.