# Is it possible to delete a directory or folder with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to delete some directories after rows relating to them are deleted. I have the folder names and they are very unique. If mysql isn't capable of doing this what are my other options (this is running on a linux server) and the folders contain numerous files.

Comment: which language do you use to delete rows ? deleting files should be done from this same script. not mysql itself

Comment: Run a bash script

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO I use php but the rows relating to the folders are deleted via a mysql temporal event

Comment: If your trigger deletes the rows from your table and inserts the folder names into a "needs to be deleted" table, then you could write a crontab that runs a script every minute that reads the "needs to be deleted" table from the database, deletes the folders in there and then removes those rows from the "needs to be deleted" table.

Answer (score 3):

this should be done from your code side (nodejs, php, etc) not on the sql side.
the delete script should delete the related folders to prevent using esoteric/complex solutions.

But, it appears that you can, according to this thread : [Invoking a PHP script from a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger)

Comment: That's really interesting. I will look into this

Comment: this particular thread is more specific to triggers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger

Comment: What if the trigger runs the PHP script to delete a directory, and then the transaction that spawned the trigger rolls back? You don't get to roll back the deletion of the directory.